# What is this Ruby typo parsing as?

Tags: ruby, parsing

Ruby has a neat safe-navigation operator. If I write `foo&.bar`, then that returns `foo.bar`, *unless* `foo` happens to be `nil`, in which case it simply short-circuits out and returns `nil`.

Now, being a programmer in a hurry, I accidentally typed `foo.&bar` with the dot and ampersand transposed. I would've expected a parse error, but I actually got

```
3.1.0 :002 > foo.&bar
(irb):2:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object (NameError)
```

In fact, if I *define* a local variable called `bar`, it seems to be just fine with it.

```
3.1.0 :003 > bar = 42
 => 42 
3.1.0 :004 > foo.&bar
 => 42
```

What is `.&` parsing as in this situation?

Comment: So what is `foo`?  You give the result of `foo.&bar` as 42 when `bar` is 42. But If I use `foo = 33`, for example, then `foo.&bar` yields 32. As currently written, your question is not reproducible.

Comment: For future reference, you can try parsing the [Ruby AST](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/RubyVM/AbstractSyntaxTree.html#method-c-parse) and seeing what structure comes out. `pp RubyVM::AbstractSyntaxTree.parse("foo.&bar")`. In this case you can see it's a `CALL` node with `:&` as the selector.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby infix operators can be called with an explicit dot, so the following two are equivalent.

```
a + b
a.+(b)
```

The same is true of the single ampersand operator, usually defined to perform the "bitwise-and" operation. And Ruby allows us to omit parentheses on argument lists unless they're needed for operator order. So `foo.&bar` is really `foo.& bar`, or less ambiguously `foo.&(bar)`, which is equivalent to an explicit call of `foo & bar`, the `def &` on whatever the type of `foo` is.